# What's the Linux equivalent of Windows ETW?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Does Linux have some event tracing framework similar to Windows ETW?  I tried a search and couldn't find any.  Perhaps LTTng is the only one?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly you want to do, Linux has at least LTTng, perf, ftrace, systemtap, and more. And with the advent of eBPF a lot of various tracing tools have appeared like mushrooms after a rain making use of it.

See e.g. https://lwn.net/Articles/803347/ for more words on the topic.